# Analytical expression for varying center of mass

Tags: circles, centroid

Imagine having a circle with center of mass in orego. I need stepwise to remove a strip from that circle (i.e. removing an arc of the circle), and for each step locate the center of mass.

An analytical expression is needed. How can this be done?

EDIT: the step - or change - would preferably be in angles.

Comment: How do you want the strip expressed in angles?

Comment: Does the circle only have mass on the perimeter itself? And when you say "remove a strip" do you mean remove an arc of the circle? Or are you slicing the circle in some other way?

Comment: with "remove a strip" I mean removing an arc of the circle. I have editting the question accordingly. Thank you for the clarifying comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming a circle of uniform density and with no mass in the interior of the circle. This means the center of mass is the same as the centroid of the (remainder of the) circle.

I've used the equations for finding centroids given in [this](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~marghitu/MECH2110/C_3.pdf/) document as inspiration (see Example 3.2).

Let the center of mass be $(X_c, Y_c)$, the radius of the circle be $R$ and the angle (from the positive x-axis) of the arc to be removed, be $\theta$. From the document we find that:$$X_c\int_{\theta}^{2\pi} {Rd\theta} = \int_{\theta}^{2\pi} {xRd\theta}$$

where $$x= Rcos(\theta)$$

Integrating, this gives $$X_cR(2\pi - \theta) = R^2(sin(2\pi) - sin(\theta))$$

or $$X_c = \frac{-Rsin(\theta)}{2\pi - \theta}$$

A similar argument for $Y_c$ gives $$Y_c = \frac{R(cos(\theta) - 1)}{2\pi - \theta}$$

For the unit circle $(R = 1)$, the movement of $(X_c, Y_c)$ as $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ gives the following nice spiral:

[image: Spiral]

Notice how the center of mass starts at origo and then moves left and down as more and more of the circle from the first quadrant is removed. When all of the circle in the first and second quadrant are removed (leaving a semi-circle in the 3rd and 4th quadrant) the center of mass is at $(X_c,Y_c) = (0, -\frac{2}{\pi})$. When only the arc in the 4th quadrant is left, $(X_c,Y_c) = (\frac{2}{\pi}, -\frac{2}{\pi})$.

Comment: How did you plot this function - I would like to plot it in Maple, but plotting Xc^2+Yc^2=1 (R=1) doesn't seem to work. Neither do ezplot or implicitplot...?

Comment: I used Excel. But why are you plotting the circle centered on $(X_c,Y_c)$? You need to plot $X_c$ and $Y_c$ as functions of $\theta$.

Comment: Are you not plotting both Xc and Yc simultaneously? I would simply like to recreate your figure, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: Start an Excel sheet. Make four columns titled "Theta(dg)", "Theta","Xc" and "Yc". Fill the first column with the angles (numbers) 0 to 359 at 1 degree intervals. In the second column convert these angles from degrees to radians. In the 3rd column insert the formula for "Xc" using the "Theta" of column 2. In the 4th column insert the formula for "Yc" using the "Theta" of column 2. Now make a scatter plot of columns "Xc" and "Yc". And you are done.